# XForms: Delete some nodes based on values in another instance

Tags: xml, xpath, orbeon, xforms

In my main instance I have a set of nodes as follows:

### Main instance

```
 <Items>
    <Item>
       <Id>2</Id>
    </Item>
    <Item>
       <Id>3</Id>
    </Item>
    <Item>
       <Id>4</Id>
    </Item>
    <Item>
       <Id>5</Id>
    </Item>
 </Items>
```

And another (similar) instance with values such as:

### Other instance

```
 <Items>
    <Item>
       <Id>4</Id>
    </Item>
    <Item>
       <Id>5</Id>
    </Item>
    <Item>
       <Id>6</Id>
    </Item>
 </Items>
```

Now I want to delete all items in the Main instance, that don't have a corresponding entry in the other Instance, so the main instance will then look like:

```
 <Items>
    <Item>
       <Id>4</Id>
    </Item>
    <Item>
       <Id>5</Id>
    </Item>
 </Items>
```

Then I want to delete all items in the other instance that DO exist in the main instance, so the other instance will look like:

```
 <Items>
    <Item>
       <Id>6</Id>
    </Item>
 </Items>
```

I'm struggling with the syntax to accomplish this. 
thanks in advance
Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<xf:delete
    ref="
        instance('main')/Item[
            not(
                Id = instance('other')/Item/Id
            )
        ]"
/>
```

and:

```
<xf:delete
    ref="
        instance('other')/Item[
            Id = instance('main')/Item/Id
        ]"
/>
```

Comment: Thanks ebruchez! Works like a charm.